# SQL Is it possible to add a comma at the end of every number within query

Tags: sql, database

i'm currently working with large lists of numbers and was wandering if it is possible to have a way of adding a comma within the query.

E.G
Before:
    `select * from table where id in (number number number number number number number number number number number number number number number number number number number number number)`

What i would like (without manually adding the comma's):
`select * from table where id in (number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number,number)`

I have tried digging an answer up but cannot find anything (most likely due to my googling skills!

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: What you want to achieve ? Why you dont want to manually put the comma ?

Comment: Your question is not clear because your first example is not a valid query.  Perhaps you have a question about an application programming language that is constructing a query, and not about SQL itself.

Comment: and where you get your list of numbers from?

Comment: No, the SQL statement should be edited before passed to the database server.

Comment: Kindly use sublime text to put the commas else make it into a dynamic query. OR use the regex option in the replace (ctrl+h)

Comment: okay thanks, i will try some of those, and yes i know the first one isnt valid i was trying to give an example of what we have to what i'd like without having to manually intervene. the information we get is from london stock exchange as well as other sources from clients and client data, mainly from txt's or another Database we have no control over. @coder of code, we have lists containing 1000's of id's manually going through and adding a comma is a lot of wasted time so trying to find a shorter way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

How about opening the query in notepad/similar, then find an replace " " (spaces) with ", "?

Or if you have many many lists, drop them into excel and automate the find and replace with some vba.